# SPARQL query to print the name, birthday pairs for a list of people in dbpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Given a list of Wikipedia article titles (people's names), how do I print the name, birthday pair for each person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using the VALUES clause in SPARQL 1.1:

```
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT ?givenName ?surname ?birth
WHERE
{      
  ?person dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?birth .      
  ?person foaf:givenName ?givenName .      
  ?person foaf:surname ?surname .      
  VALUES ?person { dbpedia:Albert_Einstein dbpedia:Max_Planck dbpedia:Marie_Curie }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you. While I have you on the line, do you know why I haven't been able to modify this query to use the ?birthSign property in dbpedia-owl? I was assuming it was automatically calculated on birthDate and so would be available for all people.